# CPT UI change custom taxonomy url

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have created new post type "groceries" and created "fruit" taxonomiy and added bunch of category but when I filter this category url shows like this `.localhost/fruit/apple` I'd like show it like `.localhost/groceries/fruit/apple` how do I do that i'm using this basic filter:

```
<li id="categories_topics">
    <?php
    $args = array(
      'show_option_none' => 'Select category',
      'taxonomy'         => 'fruit',
      'field'            => 'slug',
      'id'               => 'cat',
    );
    ?>

  <?php wp_dropdown_categories( $args ); ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("cat");
    function onCatChange() {
      if ( dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value > 0 ) {
        var str = $( "#cat option:selected" ).text();
        str = str.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
        location.href = "<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>?fruit="+str
      }
    }
    dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
    -->
  </script>
</li>
```

when I go: `.localhost/groceries/fruit/apple` it shows 404 but `.localhost/fruit/apple` works fine

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this when you register your taxonomy in `register_taxonomy()`

Pass the rewrite argument and customize to your needs:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'groceries/fruit', 'with_front' => false)
```

You'll probably need to flush your permalinks in Settings as well.

Comment: so close, when I add: add_action( 'init', 'fruit_slug' );

function fruit_slug() {
  register_taxonomy(
    'fruit',
    array(
      'label' => __( 'Fruit' ),
      'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'groceries/fruit' ),
    )
  );
} i got error in settings permalink "parameter 1 to be string, array given in ... wp-includes\media.php on line 2726"

Comment: No. Don't do that. Add the rewrite argument to your register_taxonomy function that creates the "fruit" taxonomy. Please provide the existing code where you've registered the taxonomy.

Comment: looks like I cant do this via cpt ui plugin https://wordpress.org/support/topic/re-writing-url